# Можно ли скрыть видео от прямого доступа?

Tags: html, видео, html5

Видео плеер реализован на основе html5 video тега. Можно ли сделать так, чтобы доступ к видео можно было получить только через плеер? Вот какая мысль есть, но её нужно доработать. Строка с прямым адресом на видео кодируется и пересылается на определенный адрес (скрипт), там при получении правильного ключа она декодируется и уже идет редирект на прямой адрес видео, если такой ключ не предоставлен то ничего не происходит. Можно ли сделать как-то, чтобы Apache по запросу определенного адреса передавал какой-то ключ (каким методом не важно)?

Comment: Всё, что бежит на хосте пользователя, полностью ему подвластно. Если браузер пользователя может увидеть видео, он может и отдать его пользователю. Можно лишь затруднить доступ для технически неопытных пользователей.

Comment: Возможно, наведет на нужные мысли http://uppod.ru/talk_2697

Comment: Как на apache разрешить доступ к определенному скрипту только с самого же этого сервера?

Comment: @VladD Полагаю, не так страшны пользователи, как роботы. И тут кажется единственный способ сделать — ссылки одноразовыми, как предлагает Pifagorych.

Comment: тут вам нужно использовать js